# How to perform Ternary operation in an SQL Insert statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to perform an insert into Postgres database by using a ternary operation?

I am trying not to write an SQL function nor pass in current_timestamp values via code.
Trying to achieve this directly in the SQL statement itself. Is this possible?

Seen examples for select queries where I could use CASE and WHEN but nothing for inserts and I don't see a WHERE clause being applicable here.

Advice if the following is achievable. Thanks.

For the value of check_time in the following, I want to pass in current_timestamp or null depending on the value of the status in the same query.

```
INSERT INTO user(name, age, status, check_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, current_timestamp);
```

I wish to modify the above to the following.

This is not a valid SQL statement but trying to achieve what this ternary would do where it inserts current_timestamp when status is 1 else insert a null value.

```
INSERT INTO user(name, age, status, check_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, status == 1 ? current_timestamp : null);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression where you pass again the value passed for the column `status`:

```
INSERT INTO "user"(name, age, status, check_time) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, CASE WHEN ? = 1 THEN current_timestamp END);
```

An alternative with the use of `INSERT ... SELECT` where you don't have to pass the `status` twice:

```
INSERT INTO "user"(name, age, status, check_time) 
SELECT t.name, t.age, t.status, CASE WHEN t.status = 1 THEN current_timestamp END
FROM (SELECT ? "name", ? age, ? status) t;
```

Comment: I don't understand the 1st query. How does it get the value 1 or anything from the 4th question mark? WHEN ? = 1, But 4th question mark is not status.

Comment: The  4th questionmark must be the status again. This is what I mean by *...where you pass again the value passed for the column status*.

Comment: Got you. Will test it out. Find the 1st option much cleaner though would have preferred to not repeat status value. Thanks.

Comment: instead of using ?, you can probably use dollar variables, like `($1, $2, $3, CASE WHEN $3 = 1....`

Comment: Readers be aware the CASE statement has an ELSE clause, which you can use to provide the alternate value to use for when `t.status != 1`. In my own example, something like `SELECT CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE value + 1 END`

Comment: @JonathanHartley In the absence of `ELSE`, the `CASE` expression returns `NULL` and this is what the OP wants: *...I want to pass in current_timestamp or null...*. So in this case there is no need for `ELSE NULL`.

Comment: @forpas Yep, good call. I was just highlighting it because that won't be the case for all readers.

Comment: ie some readers will want a ternary operator where neither of the values is null.